# Rename multiple files by prefix taken from folder names, bash

Tags: linux, bash, debian, pattern-matching

I have a sequence of folders containing mp4 files (one mp4 in one folder).
Folders are numbered sequentially like this example:

```
.. ..
18. Lesson 18 - Sketching a design to cut out
19. Lesson 19 - How to create a sweep
.. ..
```

the .mp4 files inside these folders are named, respectively:

```
.. ..
1. Sketching a design to cut out.mp4
1. Creating a sweep.mp4
.. ...
```

So all .mp4 file names start with "1." regardless of the folder name.
I want to rename all mp4 files with an ascending prefix taken from the folder number, i.e.

```
18. Sketching a design to cut out.mp4
19. Creating a sweep.mp4
.. ..
```

for this I want to use the following bash script:

```
for f in *.mp4; do mv "$f" "$(echo "$f" | sed s/1./MYNUMBER/)"; done
```

How to specify a sequential prefix taken from folder names instead of 'MYNUMBER'? Folder names and filenames both include whitespace. Possibly, there is another way though.

Comment: `for f in */*.mp4; do n=${f%%[!0-9]*}; [[ $n ]] && echo mv "$f" "${f/"/1"/"/$n"}"; done` ? remove `echo` if output looks correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using [Perl's `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730894/what-about-rename-different-versions-and-usage-what-is-the-recommended-way-to/730895#730895) (usable in any OS):

##### Hierarchy:

```
tree
.
├── 18. Lesson 18 - Sketching a design to cut out
│   └── 1. Sketching a design to cut out.mp4
└── 19. Lesson 19 - How to create a sweep
    └── 1. Creating a sweep.mp4

2 directories, 2 files
```

##### Code:

```
rename -n 's@\./(\d+\.)[^/]+/\d+\.\s*(.*)@$1 $2@' ./*/*.mp4
rmdir *
ls -1
```

##### Output:

```
'18. Sketching a design to cut out.mp4'
'19. Creating a sweep.mp4'
```

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `(` | group and capture to \1: |
| `\d+` | digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `\.` | . |
| `)` | end of \1 |
| `[^/]+` | any character except: `/` (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `/` | / |
| `\d+` | digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `\.` | . |
| `\s*` | whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `(` | group and capture to \2: |
| `.*` | any character except \n (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `)` | end of \2 |

Comment: Is there a "dry run" option to check output on terminal before actually running script? (for both solutions)

Comment: Yes, this is the purpose of `-n`

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for something like this:

```
for src in */*.mp4; do
  dst=${src%/*}/${src%% *}${src#*/*.}
  echo mv "$src" "$dst"
done
```

Remove `echo` if the output looks good.

Comment: All 3 scripts work correctly and do their job. I would accept all 3 answers if it were possible.@jhnc answer seems contains shorter source code; Gilles Quénot explains things in a more expilicit way, it also moves mp4s out of its folders to the top directory and removes empty folders: although this wasn't required, but this could be useful. Plus thanks for the 'tree' command tip. oguz ismail's code is also short and helpful. I decided to choose Gilles Quénot's answer, for some extra info. Thank you!